Could not parse the remainder: '()' from 'topic_files.items()'
I am working on a Django project where I need to display files grouped by topics for a specific submission. Each submission is associated with multiple topics, and each topic can have multiple files. I am encountering an issue when trying to render this in a template.
Models:
from django.db import models
from users.models import UserProfile

# Create your models here.
class ResearchWork(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField()
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
    
class Topic(models.Model):
    research_work = models.ForeignKey(ResearchWork, related_name='topics', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    
    def __str__(self):
        if self.research_work is None:
            return f"Unassigned - {self.name}"
        return f"{self.research_work.name} - {self.name}"

class Assignment(models.Model):
    student = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, related_name='student_assignment', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    teacher = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, related_name='teacher_assignment', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    is_accepted = models.BooleanField(default=False) # charfield
    is_reviewed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    text = models.TextField(blank=True)
    
    
    def __str__(self):
        return f"Assignment for {self.student.user.username} with {self.teacher.user.username}"
    
    
class Submission(models.Model):
    assignment = models.ForeignKey(Assignment, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    SEMESTER_CHOICES = (
        ('1', 'Semester 1'),
        ('2', 'Semester 2'),
        ('3', 'Semester 3'),
        ('4', 'Semester 4'),
        ('5', 'Semester 5'),
        ('6', 'Semester 6'),
        ('7', 'Semester 7'),
        ('8', 'Semester 8'),
    )
    semester = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, choices=SEMESTER_CHOICES)
    research_work = models.ForeignKey(ResearchWork, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
    
    
    def __str__(self):
        research_work_name = "No Research Work Assigned" if self.research_work is None else self.research_work.name
        return f"{research_work_name} - for student {self.assignment.student.user.username} in semester - {self.semester}"

 


class File(models.Model):
    topic = models.ForeignKey(Topic, related_name='files', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    submission = models.ForeignKey(Submission, related_name='files', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    filename = models.FileField(upload_to='submissions/', null=True)
    upload_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    is_accepted = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_reviewed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    comment = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True) 
     
    def __str__(self):
        return f"File: {self.filename.name} for Topic: {self.topic.name}"
    

View Function:
def admin_submission_details(request, sub_id):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        submission = get_object_or_404(Submission, pk=sub_id)
        topics = Topic.objects.filter(research_work=submission.research_work)
        topic_files = {topic: File.objects.filter(topic=topic, submission=submission) for topic in topics}
        context = {'submission':submission, 'topics':topics, 'topic_files':topic_files}
        return render(request, 'users/admin_submission_details.html', context=context)
    else:
        messages.error(request, 'Invalid user')
        return redirect('login') 

Template:
{% block content %}
<div class="body flex-grow-1 px-3">
  <div class="container-lg">
    {% for topic, files in topic_files.items() %}
    <div class="card mb-4">
      <div class="card-header">
        <strong>{{topic.name}}</strong>
      </div>
      <div class="card-body">
        <div class="example">
          <div class="table table-responsive">
            <table class="table align-middle">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <td style="width: 20%" scope="col">Файл</td>
                  <td style="width: 20%" scope="col">Дата</td>
                  <td style="width: 20%" scope="col">Статус проверки</td>
                  <td style="width: 20%" scope="col">Комментарий</td>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                {% for file in files %}
                <tr>
                  <td>
                    <a href="{{file.filename.url}}" target="_blank"
                      >{{ file.filename}}</a
                    >
                  </td>
                  <td>{{ file.upload_date|date:"Y-m-d H:i"}}</td>
                  {% if file.is_reviewed %} {% if file.is_accepted %}
                  <td style="color: green">Принято</td>
                  {% else %}
                  <td style="color: red">Не принято</td>
                  {% endif %} {% else %}
                  <td style="color: orange">На проверке</td>
                  {% endif %}
                  <td>{{file.comment}}</td>
                </tr>
                {% endfor %}
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
          {% if not topic_files[topic] %}
          <div class="alert alert-warning" role="alert">
            No files uploaded for this topic yet.
          </div>
          {% endif %}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
  </div>
</div>
<script>
  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    const clickableRows = document.querySelectorAll(".clickable-row");
    clickableRows.forEach((row) => {
      row.addEventListener("click", function () {
        window.location.href = this.getAttribute("data-href");
      });
    });
  });
</script>
{% endblock content %} 


When I try to render this template, I encounter the following error:
django.template.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: Could not parse the remainder: '()' from 'topic_files.items()' 

How can I correctly display the files grouped by their topics in my Django template? I have tried different approaches and every time I get the same error. Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Please try to create a proper [mre] by removing whatever is not necessary from the example to demonstrate the problem.

In Django templates, you don't call functions. If the item is callable, the template will call it, without parameters, so:
{% for topic, files in topic_files.items %}
    <!-- … -->
{% endfor %}
